# Getting a "invalid option: -Ku (OptionParser::InvalidOption)" when trying to run script/console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `script/console` on our production box:

```
/data/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/console.rb:11:in `block in <top (required)>': invalid option: -Ku (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from /data/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/console.rb:6:in `new'
    from /data/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.11/lib/commands/console.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/console:3:in `require'
    from script/console:3:in `<main>'
```

As you can see from the output, we're using Rails 2.3.11. Our Ruby version is 1.9.2 (p180).

The same thing happens when we try to run `script/delayed_job start`:

```
/data/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.0.7/lib/delayed/command.rb:51:in `initialize': invalid option: -Ku (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
    from script/delayed_job:5:in `new'
    from script/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to Ruby 1.9.2-p290 fixes this problem.